# Python String Capitalize

Tags: python, capitalize

```
from string import capwords

t = "\"i'm happy,\" said tanby"
sText = t.split()
rText = []

for str in sText:
    if '\"' in str[0]:
        t = capwords(str, sep='\"')
        rText.append(t)
    else:
        t = capwords(str)
        rText.append(t)

print(' '.join(rText))

>>> "I'm Happy," Said Tanby
     ^   ^       ^    ^
```

Ignore quotes and capitalize.
When used `title()`, become *" I'M* and when used `capwords()`, become *" i'm*.
Is there a better way?

Comment: So you want to capitalize every word independantly?

Comment: [NLTK might help.](http://www.nltk.org/)

Comment: That's right. But I'm just looking for a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes interfere with the `capwords` algorithm.  Using `re.sub` with a pattern allowing single quotes in words fixes it.  The regular expression matches one or more `\w` (word characters) or single quotes.  Each match is passed to the lambda function and capitalized for the replacement.

```
>>> import re
>>> s='"i\'m happy," said tanby'
>>> print(re.sub(r"\b[\w']+\b",lambda m: m.group().capitalize(),s))
"I'm Happy," Said Tanby
```

Comment: I see. It's a regular expression. Nice.